# Auto open a namespace in F#

Tags: f#, module, namespaces

Hi would like to know how to make the f# compiler to auto open a namespace automatically.

I have

```
namespace XXX 

I have to add something here do(AutoOpen("XXX.YYY")) or something like that to make the XXX.YYY module to be opened when referencing the library from external projects.

[<AutoOpen>]
module YYY = 
    ....
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Is auto-open module not enough for you?

Comment: No I want that as soon I have reference the library from an external project the path to XXX.YYY is automatically open and I can access the function that are in module XXX.YYY I know it is looking like what I have in my code snippet but I dont remember exactly

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to open a namespace/module without opening its parent first, you have to add the attribute on assembly level.
You can do this by adding an AssemblyInfo.fs file to your project:

In the case of the following code:

```
namespace Framework

module GlobalFunctions = 

  let Test () =
    10.
```

You would for instance add the following code to AssemblyInfo.fs:

```
namespace Framework

[<assembly:AutoOpen("Framework.GlobalFunctions")>]

do()
```

And then you can call the code from a script (.fsx) file with:

```
#r @"C:\PathToAssembly\Assembly.dll"

let result = Test ()
```

Resulting in:

```
--> Referenced 'C:\PathToAssembly\Assembly.dll'
val result : float = 10.0
```

Answer (score 4):

The `AutoOpen` attribute can be applied only to F# `module`, so you won't be able to add it to an entire `namespace`. However, since you can place all F# declarations inside a module, that may be enough for what you need. The syntax is:

```
[<AutoOpen>]
module MyGlobals =
  // Declarations in the module
  type Foo() = 
    member x.Bar = 10
```

When you reference the assembly, you should see `Foo` immediately. If the declaration is placed inside another namespace (i.e. `MyLibrary`), then you'll need to add `open MyLibrary`, but `MyGlobals` will be accessible automatically.

Comment: Hi Tomas, see my previous comment to pad. What I want is slighly different to what you are suggesting